# Difference between Base64 in java.util and commons-net packages?

Tags: java

What are the differences between `Base64` in `java.util` and `commons-net` packages?

They are related or they are not and what they do?

I have tried it for `FtpHttpClient` but I also have that class in `java.util.`.

Why `commons-net.Base64` instead of `java.util.Base64`?

Comment: I’m pretty sure the Commons one existed before java.util.Base64.  It’s better to use java.util.Base64, because code with fewer external dependencies is more reusable.

Answer (score 0):

> > what are the difference between Base64 in java.util and commons-net packages?

The difference is in the RFC spec which use to decode: RFC 4648 vs RFC 2045.

> > They are related or not and what they do?

not for sure